# Javascript conditional-operator operator in string throws error

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm getting this unexpected behavior of an undefined property in the true clauses of the conditional-operator:

Example:
Javascript:

```
var obj = undefined;

console.log("hello world" + (obj) ? obj.Name.toString(): "Object not defined");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJkUB/1/)

The expeced behaviour is getting a log entry saying `hello worldObject`"not defined instead an error is thrown: `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'Name': object is null or undefined` . How can this be, the object is checked an it should never execute htis coe path.
A working example is:

```
var obj = undefined;

console.log("hello world" + ((obj) ? obj.Name.toString(): "Object not defined"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZBwA/)

Comment: Just to clarify - is this an operator precedence question?

Comment: I too am wondering about what the question is (and why there are parenthesis around obj in first code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping's the issue here - your line is equivalent to the following:

```
("hello world" + obj) ? obj.Name.toString(): "Object not defined"
```

`("hello world" + obj)` is equal to `"hello worldundefined"`, which is coerced into a `true` boolean in JavaScript, so the browser attempts to find and run the `obj.Name.toString()` function, which does not exist.

Also, I'm pretty sure most objects don't have a `Name` property, unless you set one manually.  The undefined value will never have a `Name` property, as it's not an object and can't be converted into one, therefore giving the error stated.

If you want to check for that specific property instead, then you'd have to do something like the following:

```
var obj = undefined;
console.log("hello world" + (typeof obj === 'object' && obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.toString(): " Object not defined"));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this condition:

```
console.log("hello world" + ((obj || {}).Name) ? ...);
```

or also

```
console.log("hello world" + ((obj || 0).Name) ? ...);
```

so you will check for both `obj` and `obj.Name`.
In fact, the condition you defined only checks for `obj` but not for `obj.Name`

You could read an explanation about this kind of condition on [ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-safety-fence-for-your-property-lookups)

Answer (score 0):

You should instead do: `(obj && obj.Name) ? obj.Name.toString(): "Object not defined"`

Your condition

```
(obj) ? obj.Name.toString(): "Object not defined"
```

checks only if `obj` is defined, it does not check if `obj.Name` is defined before calling `.toString()` on it.